# USB not getting mounted due to Read-Only

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, read-only

Here is the image:
[image: My image]

I have tried the following command but got nothing:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sde

/dev/sde:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

Kindly, help me in this situation.

**Edited output of the command `dmesg -w`

Here is the output [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/528680eed9902e326fe65b2d03492b5a)

Comment: It would help if you add the output of `dmesg -w` when you plug the usb

Comment: sure.. Let me edit the output of the command.

Comment: I didn't explain correctly, sorry. `dmesg` shows the kernel messages. `dmesg -w` leaves these open and live updates. What it might help you is to disconnect the USB, type `dmesg -w` and then connect the USB. You will see new messages appearing related to your USB and you might see an error message if the device is damaged. Ubuntu configuration often states that if  there are errors reading a system, is mounted read only and this is what I was trying to figure out. If you don't mind losing the information in the drive, reformatting it may help. Have a look at `fdisk`,  `gparted` or others.

Comment: @Katu Thank you for the explanation. But what I should do if my pen drive is corrupted or damaged? Please can you help me in making it operational again?

Comment: If it's the /dev/sdd device that your dmesg shows, it doesn't look damaged. Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I tried that still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try restoring the USB drive to a standard format. There is a utility called `mkusb`. Look at this [link](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Add the ppa, update apt and then `sudo apt install mkusb` and when done, run `mkusb`.

Step by step instructions. Run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb
mkusb
```

and select **option d** see below:

[image]

if prompted for root password, enter it. Follow the insturctions on the screen:

and then select the **Restore to a Standard Storage Device** option (**WARNING: you will loose all your data on the USB drive**):

[image]
[image]

That should do it.

Comment: I got error: [Error gist](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/7f5ab6887bb84c051ccc8a549a6490b3). Kindly, let me know what I can do.

Comment: I might know what's happening. in `/media` there should be a directory with your user name. In the past I had similar issues and I found that the directory was owned by `root` and after I changed the owner/group to my user name, the issue went away. In the terminal, type: `ls /media/$USER -dl` and for owner / group, see if it says `root root` and if so, I believe that's the issue. You can try changing the permissions to your user name and try it again.

Comment: How I can change the permissions ? Please guide me.

Comment: I have tried changing the permissions. See the [gist of error](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/48483490eb3695a6cacb45bb3fe66493) I have got.

Comment: I just noticed this, `/dev/sdd1: No such file or directory` and to me this indicates an issue with your partition table on the disk. Are you experienced with GParted? You can try creating a new partition table: *Device->Create Partition Table* and then create different partitions. Select the msdos version. You will lose all your data.

Comment: I tried Gparted Editor but is of no use to me.